# How can I change the Android Studio Theme Default so text is visible on the Tab header

Tags: android-studio, android-theme

The Tab Header background in Android Studio 1.5.1 is black and I cannot read the tab name.  How can I change the background so I can read the text?

[image]

Comment: Rephrase question and add image directly

Answer (score 0):

Try this : File > Other Settings > Default Settings... > Appearance & Behaviour > File Color

And then you select "Use in Editor Tab".

The color of tabs should match your configuration (by default, green for tests, etc.)

PS : same option is available in the main preferences menu.

Comment: Nothing happens ! i follow this.  "Use in Editor Tab" already checked and color also same.  and then  when i restart my studio it rechange to my  dark theme. i want to reset my theme as default studio theme. @Coralie B

Comment: Facing same problem. I think it's a bug in AS. Changing themes generally doesn't change everything... Going to Editor/Editor Tabs/ and selecting Placement/Left makes it more readable, but the colour is still grey...